# Elm DOM not rerendering on model change

Tags: elm

I have the following Elm code:

```
tomorrowTasks : WebData (List Task) -> Html Msg
tomorrowTasks response = 
  div []
    [ maybeList response 
    , span [ hidden ( model.showNewTaskLoader == False ) ] 
       [ indeterminateLoader ]
    ]
```

`maybeList` and `indeterminateLoader` are just some other view elements.

Whenever I change `model.showNewTaskLoader` in my update-Function, I can see that `model.showNewTaskLoader` is indeed changing (via the explore history overlay from elm-reactor). However the `indeterminateLoader` stays hidden.

Why is the DOM not updating the visibility of the element?

Comment: Can you check in browser's dev tools to see if the attribute is being toggled or not?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "stays hidden" means? Have you used the web inspector to determine that the span's inline styles aren't actually changing? Alternatively, have you tried adding another element (e.g. `text "foo"`) to the span's child list to see if the problem is with `indeterminateLoader` and not the span?

Comment: I found the error. The `model` variable I used was the initial model I created, not the current model. 
Additionally `hidden` only works on form elements like `input`, so I am now using css visibility to hide the element.